# Centos RPM with python virtual env

Tags: python, centos, packaging, rpm, rpmbuild

I am trying to deploy my python virtualenv as centos rpm.

Following steps I have taken.

1. Created virtual environment with required dependencies.

One of requirement is pyOpenSSL

2. Built rpm package.
3. Now when installed on fresh centos instance, I am getting error as 
   'No module named OpenSSL'.

Is there any different procedure for pyOpenSSL module or do we need to install openssl-devel and openssl explicitly on new machine.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very good idea. A virtualenv isn't meant to be a "system installation" like you'd put in an RPM package. And an RPM package that creates a virtualenv and then calls `pip` inside it is especially weird. Why not just create a portable virtualenv and tar it up, or use a tool like pyInstaller, cx_Freeze, zc_buildout, etc.? Or just create a normal Python package with setuptools requirements (and, if necessary, set up a local PyPI proxy to fetch those packages from)?

Comment: Thanks for info. I did mistakes. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any different procedure for pyOpenSSL module or do we need to install openssl-devel and openssl explicitely on new machine.

First, I'm pretty sure `pyOpenSSL` only requires `openssl-devel` as a *build* dependency, not a runtime dependency. So, as long as you're distributing a pre-built copy (whether by tarring up a portable virtualenv, using a wheel file in a custom repo, or otherwise), `openssl-devel` shouldn't be a problem, only `openssl`.

But `openssl` *is* a problem. [`pyOpenSSL`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL) is a pure-Python wrapper; all it does is `dlopen` the `.so` file and call a bunch of functions out of it. Without the `.so`, it can't do anything useful at all.

I'm a bit surprised that any (non-embedded) linux distro doesn't come with OpenSSL. If CentOS comes with `openssl` pre-installed, then you already have all your dependencies, and there's nothing to do here.

But, given that, as far as I know, OpenSSL still isn't part of [LSB](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb), this is at least a *conceivable* problem, so let's deal with it.

---

As a brief sidebar: If you switched to a different OpenSSL wrapper (there are at least three major alternatives) that's written in C (or SWIG or SIP) rather than Python and links OpenSSL directly rather than by `cffi`, everything would be a lot simpler. For example, I believe with M2Crypto, all you have to do is create a static-only build of OpenSSL, then build `M2Crypto` with `--openssl=/path/to/static/openssl`, and you're done.

---

But if you're set on `pyOpenSSL`, is there any way around this? Yes, but it's not going to be easy.

The good news is that `pyOpenSSL` isn't a wrapper around OpenSSL itself, but the lower-level [`cryptography`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography) module. And `cryptography` uses `cffi` rather than `ctypes`, which means it can be distributed with a pre-built helper module, which can be statically linked against OpenSSL.

Unfortunately, while `cryptography` does have built-in support for pre-building its helpers with statically linked OpenSSL on Windows, last time I checked, it did *not* have that support on other platforms. That means you're either going to need to add that support yourself, or trick it in some way.

If you don't know much about this stuff, you're almost certainly going to need step-by-step help with this. Read the docs on `cffi`, and both the [Building `cryptography` on Linux](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) docs and the bundled `INSTALL` file, and make sure you understand static linking and GNU ld, and then go to the cryptography-dev mailing list. Or maybe go to [the bug tracker](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues) and search for or create an issue for static linking OpenSSL on linux.

But if you know what you're doing, here's the basic idea:

1. To build in static linking support, look in the [OpenSSL binding](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py) and [binding utilities](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py) source to see what it does on Windows and do the equivalent on Linux.
2. To work around it, what you want to do is build OpenSSL locally, copy it inside the `cryptography` source tree, trick `cryptography` into link to `libopenssl.so` (and friends) with relative rather than absolute paths, and modify its [`setup.py`](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/setup.py) to copy the .so files into the package itself.
3. If you want to get really hacky, instead of modifying `setup.py`, just copy the .so files into the package manually after installation. (This will obviously only work if you're using a distribution mechanism based on bundling up the virtualenv, rather than rebuilding it.)

---

Another option is to use an executable packager to automatically bundle any dependent non-system libraries into the executable. Unfortunately, the only one I know of that does that kind of thing on linux is `pyInstaller`, and [last I checked](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) it didn't know how to handle `cryptography`/`pyOpenSSL`, so again you'd have to figure it out and extend `pyInstaller` yourself. If you want to go this way, take a look at the other recipes there. Also, I believe [`py2app`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) can handle `pyOpenSSL`; while it's Mac-specific, looking at what it does may help you do the same on linux.